# Save Snapchat text history

Tags: android, chat, snapchat

So I always have an issue of seeing a response to a question I asked previously, and forgetting what that question was. Hence, rendering the given response useless. My conversations usually end up something like the following.

> Them: I dont know XD
>   Me: Dont know what?

The response `They` gave me is usually an answer to a question like:

> Me: What was your last response to?

Complete conversations with all history recorded would look something such as:

> Me: Whats your favorite color?
>   Them: Blue.
>   Me: What about blue?
>   Them: I don't remember.
>   Me: Don't remember what?
>   Them: What are you talking about?
>   Me: huh?

And so on and so forth.

Is there a way that I can record and display previous messages, without tapping to save every-single-one?

I was thinking maybe an Xposed module or a background process …

Android. Rooted. Cyanogenmod.